# How can I access methods in a subclass

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, subclass

I am currently learning Java and I'm really struggling with something. So I have a Class "Disk" with the subclasses "CD","Game", and "DVD". I have a "database" class which creates new instances of disk,game and cd in an array list. The array list is initialised like so:

```
private ArrayList<Disk> disks = new ArrayList();
```

I then add an instance of Game to the array:

```
disks.add(new Game(1999,"SuperGame!",900,"xbox","ea"));
```

I'm trying to access a method, "getConsole" in the Game subclass using the following code:

```
Disk currentDisk = disks.get(3);
currentDisk.getConsole();
```

It says the getConsole method doesn't exist. I can see the problem is that it's only accessing the Disk class' methods and fields but how can I make it so it can access the methods of the subclass that it is defined as. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 4):

Since `getConsole()` is available only on the `Game` subclass, you need to tell Java that you know you're looking at a `Game`, and cast explicitly:

```
Disk currentDisk = disks.get(3);
if (currentDisk instanceof Game) {
    ((Game)currentDisk).getConsole();
}
```

This is not a very good way to do things in Java, because you are explicitly testing for the type of subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it back to `Game`:

```
  Game myGame = (Game)disks.get(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Disk doesn't know about a method in Game, in order to use it, you'll need to cast it as a Game. You should also in most cases check to make sure that it is infact a Game and not another subclass type.

```
Disk disk = new Game();

(Game)disk.getConsole(); // notice the cast
```

Edit: Forgot to add, to check if it's of a type use instanceof

```
if (disk instanceof Game)
{
    // do things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check if the object is actually a "Game" object by using instanceof operator. Then you can cast it to Game and use it for accessing all game public members and methods.

```
Disk currentDisk = disks.get(3);
if (currentDisk instanceof Game) {
 Game game = (Game) currentDisk;
 game.getConsole();
}
```